# rowspan and colspan in html

Tags: c#, html

I was doing all this in C#

I created a table like below

```
 Company Name    Gender

  cmc    sindhu  f
  cmc    shilpa  f
  cmc    srikar  m
```

But what I need is....I want "cmc" to appear only once for all the names.

```
  Company Name    Gender

  cmc     sindhu  f
          shilpa  f
          srikar  m
```

How can I use `rowspan` and `colspan` for this? My code is as follows:

```
  public class sample

{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DataTable table=new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("Company", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Gender", typeof(string));

        table.Rows.Add("cmc", "sindhu", "f");
        table.Rows.Add("cmc", "shilpa", "f");
        table.Rows.Add("cmc", "srikar", "m");


        string htmltable; 
        string htmlstring;
        htmltable=ConvertDataTableToHtml(table);
        string filename = "HTML File.html";
        StreamWriter swXLS = new StreamWriter( "c:\\"+ filename);
        swXLS.Write(htmltable.ToString());
        swXLS.Close();

    }
            public static string ConvertDataTableToHtml(DataTable targetTable)
            {
                string htmlString = "";

                if (targetTable == null)
                {
                throw new System.ArgumentNullException("targetTable");
                }

                StringBuilder htmlBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                //Create Top Portion of HTML Document
                htmlBuilder.AppendLine("<html>");
                htmlBuilder.AppendLine("<head>");
                htmlBuilder.AppendLine("</head>");
                htmlBuilder.AppendLine("<body>");
                htmlBuilder.AppendLine("<table border='1px' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='0'>");

                //Create Header Row
                htmlBuilder.Append("<span style='font-size: small;font-weight:bold;'></span>\n");
                htmlBuilder.AppendLine("\n<tr align='left' valign='top'>");

                foreach (DataColumn targetColumn in targetTable.Columns)
                {

                htmlBuilder.Append("<td  align='left' valign='top'>");
                htmlBuilder.Append("<b>");
                htmlBuilder.Append(targetColumn.ColumnName);
                htmlBuilder.Append("</b>");
                htmlBuilder.Append("</td>\n");
                }

                htmlBuilder.AppendLine("</tr>");

                //Create Data Rows
                foreach (DataRow myRow in targetTable.Rows)
                {
                htmlBuilder.AppendLine("\n<tr align='left' valign='top'>");

                foreach (DataColumn targetColumn in targetTable.Columns)
                {
                htmlBuilder.Append("<td  align='left' valign='top'>");
                htmlBuilder.Append(myRow[targetColumn.ColumnName].ToString());
                htmlBuilder.Append("</td>\n");
                }
                //htmlBuilder.Append("</td>");
                htmlBuilder.AppendLine("</tr>\n");
                }

                //Create Bottom Portion of HTML Document
                htmlBuilder.AppendLine("</table>");
                htmlBuilder.AppendLine("</body>");
                htmlBuilder.AppendLine("</html>");

                //Create String to be Returned
                htmlString = htmlBuilder.ToString();

                return htmlString;
            }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        //create Data Row
        int count = 0;
        int rowsinserted = 0;

        foreach (DataRow myRow in targetTable.Rows)
        {
            htmlBuilder.AppendLine("\n<tr  align='left' valign='top'>");

            foreach (DataColumn targetColumn in targetTable.Columns)
            {

                if (targetColumn == targetTable.Columns[0])
                {
                    if (count == 0)
                    {
                        htmlBuilder.Append("<td rowspan='" + targetTable.Rows.Count + "' 'align='left' valign='top'>");
                        htmlBuilder.Append(myRow[targetColumn.ColumnName].ToString());
                        htmlBuilder.Append("</td>\n");
                    }

                }
                else

                {
                    int columncount = 1; 
                    for (int i = 1; i < targetTable.Columns.Count; i++)
                    {

                        if (targetColumn == targetTable.Columns[columncount])
                        {

                            htmlBuilder.Append("<td 'align='left' valign='top'>");
                            htmlBuilder.Append(myRow[targetColumn.ColumnName].ToString());
                            htmlBuilder.Append("</td>\n");


                        }
                        columncount = columncount + 1;

                        count = count + 1;
                    }
            }
            }
            rowsinserted = rowsinserted + 1;
            htmlBuilder.AppendLine("</tr>\n");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the below should work, I've not tested it though. Basically I am trying to determine when I hit the first occurrence of a value in the first column and add a cell that spans as many rows as there are occurrences of that value. This will only work if the rows are sorted by the first column.

```
//Create Data Rows
foreach (DataRow myRow in targetTable.Rows)
{
    htmlBuilder.AppendLine("\n<tr align='left' valign='top'>");
    foreach (DataColumn targetColumn in targetTable.Columns)
    {
        // if its the first column then only add a cell when its the first time 
        // value appears, else just add the cell
        if(targetColumn == targetTable.Columns.First())
        {
            // if its the first time the value has appeared in the first column
            // then add cell with rowspan set to the number of appearances
            if(myRow == targetTable.Rows.First(r => r[targetColumn.ColumnName].ToString() == myRow[targetColumn.ColumnName].ToString()))
            {
                rowspan = targetTable.Rows.Count(r => r[targetColumn.ColumnName].ToString() == myRow[targetColumn.ColumnName].ToString());

                htmlBuilder.Append("<td  rowspan='"+rowspan+"' align='left' valign='top'>");
                htmlBuilder.Append(myRow[targetColumn.ColumnName].ToString());
                htmlBuilder.Append("</td>\n");
            }
        }
        else
        {              
            htmlBuilder.Append("<td  align='left' valign='top'>");
            htmlBuilder.Append(myRow[targetColumn.ColumnName].ToString());
            htmlBuilder.Append("</td>\n");
        }
    }

    htmlBuilder.AppendLine("</tr>\n");
}
```

**EDIT: Assuming you don't have to use `DataTable`**

This works, I've tested it, and you can view the output [here](http://jsfiddle.net/CPBV4/). I have assumed that you don't have to use `DataTable` as it is much easier to use enumerables like `List` and `Dictionary`. Ideally you'd probably want to create your own class instead of using the `Dictionary` but I think it works ok for demonstration purposes.

```
var Data = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();

Data.Add(new Dictionary<string, string>() { {"Company", "Company 1"}, {"Name", "Jim"}, {"Gender", "m"} });
Data.Add(new Dictionary<string, string>() { {"Company", "Company 1"}, {"Name", "Bob"}, {"Gender", "m"} });
Data.Add(new Dictionary<string, string>() { {"Company", "Company 1"}, {"Name", "Dawn"}, {"Gender", "f"} });
Data.Add(new Dictionary<string, string>() { {"Company", "Company 2"}, {"Name", "Dave"}, {"Gender", "m"} });
Data.Add(new Dictionary<string, string>() { {"Company", "Company 2"}, {"Name", "Ben"}, {"Gender", "m"} });
Data.Add(new Dictionary<string, string>() { {"Company", "Company 2"}, {"Name", "Tina"}, {"Gender", "f"} });
Data.Add(new Dictionary<string, string>() { {"Company", "Company 2"}, {"Name", "Sarah"}, {"Gender", "f"} });

string html = "<table><tr>";

foreach (var Column in Data.First().Select(col => col.Key))
{
    html += string.Format("<th>{0}</th>", Column);
}

html += "</tr>";

foreach (var Row in Data)
{
    html += "<tr>";

    foreach (string Column in Row.Select(col => col.Key))
    {
        if(Column == Row.First().Key)
        {
            if(Row == Data.First(row => row.First(col => col.Key == Column).Value == Row.First(col => col.Key == Column).Value))
            {
                int Row_Span = Data.Count(row => row.First(col => col.Key == Column).Value == Row.First(col => col.Key == Column).Value);

                html += string.Format("<td rowspan='{0}'>{1}</td>", Row_Span, Row.First(col => col.Key == Column).Value);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            html += string.Format("<td>{0}</td>", Row.First(col => col.Key == Column).Value);
        }
    }

    html += "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: 'System.Data.DataRowCollection' does not contain a definition for 'OrderBy' and no extension method 'OrderBy' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.DataRowCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)----this error was coming.i also tried adding System.Data.DataRowCollection.but showing the same error.

Comment: No, sorry I just assumed it was some type of enumerable. You should be able to dump the `OrderBy`s if you sort the data by the first column before you add it to the `DataTable`. I will update my answer accordingly

Comment: Now i was getting the same error like ORDERBY for FIRST and COUNT

Comment: yeah, that'll be the same issue, they are methods on enumerables. maybe you can use `[0]` instead of `First()` and `Length` instead of `Count`. How attached are you to using the `DataTable` object?

Comment: sorry i am fresher and i was not getting my required output

Comment: I have updated my answer, hopefully that will do the job